# Why is the strong number being displayed once in the code?

Tags: c

The code is not printing all the strong numbers in the given range of lower limit and upper limit. It is only printing 1. Cannot find either logical or syntax error. Please help.

New to C programming. Was practicing C questions online. The question was about to print all the strong numbers.

```
int strong (int lower_limit,int upper_limit)
{
   int i,temp1,temp2,product=1,sum=0;

   for(i=lower_limit;i<=upper_limit;i++)
   {
      temp1=i;

      while(temp1!=0)
      {
         temp2=temp1%10;
         for( ;temp2>0;temp2--)
         {
            product=temp2*product;
         }
         temp1/=10;                
         sum=sum+product;
      }

      if(i==sum)
         printf("%d is a strong number\n",i);
   }

   return 0;
}

int main()
{
   int lower_limit,upper_limit;

   printf("Enter lower limit number\n");
   scanf("%d",&lower_limit);

   printf("Enter upper limit number\n");
   scanf("%d",&upper_limit);

   strong(lower_limit,upper_limit);

   return 0;
}
```

If I put lower_limit as 1 and upper_limit as 1000 I am supposed to get 1,2,and 145.

Comment: Please make a small effort and format/indent your code properly. For example like the samples in your C text book. Also please tell us what a "strong number" is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `sum` and `product` are never reset. To avoid such cases, it's better to declare the variable where is really needed. Otherwise you end up with temporary states if you forget to reset/update the values

This should work:

```
int strong(int lower_limit, int upper_limit) {
    int i, temp1, temp2, product = 1, sum = 0;

    for (i = lower_limit; i <= upper_limit; i++) {
        temp1 = i;
        sum = 0; // should be reset when iterating through interval

        while (temp1 != 0) {
            temp2 = temp1 % 10;
            product = 1; // should reset for each digit
            for (; temp2 > 0; temp2--) {
                product = temp2 * product;
            }
            temp1 /= 10;
            sum = sum + product;
        }

        if (i == sum)
            printf("%d is a strong number\n", i);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int i ,rem ,num , fact=1, result=0;
int tempnum = num;

while(tempnum != 0)
{
    rem = tempnum % 10; // gives the remainder
    for(i=1;i<=rem;i++)
    {
        fact = fact * i;
    }
    result += fact;
    fact = 1; //to repeat the loop keeping fact as 1 because the value will change after every loop
    tempnum /= 10 ;
}
```